# Traits for modifying interfaces in scala

Tags: scala, hash

Can some one please explain the below example in the book "Programming in Scala" by Martin Odersky related to use of traits for modifying interfaces.

```
trait HashCaching {
  private var cachedHash: Int = 0
  private var hashComputed: Boolean = false

  /** Override the default Java hash computation */
  override def hashCode = {
    if (!hashComputed) {
      cachedHash = super.hashCode
      hashComputed = true
    }
    cachedHash
  }
}
```

However, attempting to use it runs into a problem:

```
class Book(val author: String, val title: String) extends Ordered[Book] with HashCaching {
  // compare and equals() as before...
  override def hashCode = {
    Thread.sleep(3000) // simulate a VERY slow hash
    author.hashCode + title.hashCode
  }
}
```

This version does not get its hash code cached! The problem is that Book’s
hashCode method overrides HashCaching’s.

Q.1 I could not understand why does the hash code does not get cached?

Then the author goes on to give the below solution:

```
abstract class BaseBook(val author: String, val title: String) {
  override def hashCode = {
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    author.hashCode + title.hashCode
  }
}
class Book(author: String, title: String) extends BaseBook(author, title) with Ordered[Book] with HashCaching {
  // compare and equals() as before...
}
```

Q.2 How does overriding hash code function in base class effects and now the hash code gets cached?

I could not understand anything in this example, please explain.

Comment: Note which implementation is called when trait calls `super` function.

Comment: Which explanation does the book give?

Comment: @Suma Trait will call java's implementation of hashcode?

Comment: Book did not give a proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your "Q1" on the line above it: "The problem is that Book’s hashCode method overrides HashCaching’s." You mix in `HashCashing`, and then override implementation, so it ends up never getting used.

In the other example, implementation is provided by `BaseBook`, then overridden by `HashCaching`, that augments it, and then inherited by `Book`. In this case `Book` does not override the implementation, so, it works as intended.